# Route is giving 404 with React

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I have a link in my site:

```
<a href="/en">
    <li className="lang">ENGLISH</li>
</a>
```

and a route:

```
<Route history={browserHistory} path="/en">
    <HomeLayoutEn />
</Route>
```

But when I click on the link, I get a 404

Initially, my link was:

```
<Link to="/en">
    <li className="lang">ENGLISH</li>
</Link>
```

But I changed it to a html link, as I have no interest with SPA Routing, and I had issues with 404 when accessing url manually.

Any idea what's failing ?

Comment: It's because `<Link />` uses React Router vs `<a>` uses normal one.

Comment: Yes, I understand, but so, <a> should work no ?

Comment: Unfortunately React routing is different from normal routing, so it won't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Link component from React-router instead of anchor tag because anchor tag will use the Browser history API whereas a Link uses the history object which is used by Router component and your entire routing is managed by Router.

Also you need to specify history on Router component instead of Route and Route component need to simply specify the path. Also you will have a single Router component at the top level of your hierarchy

```
<Router history={browserHistory} >
    <Route path="/en" component={HomeLayoutEn} />
</Router>
```

and Link will be used as

```
<Link to="/en">
    <li className="lang">ENGLISH</li>
</Link>
```

Now if you wish to use the `anchor tag` without SPA then for each Route you need to generate a different bundle output html